# Where should I place firebase initialisation in react-native project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

where should I place firebase initialisation in react-native project and how I should gives access to that in rest of my project?
Here is my project structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koKeX.png)

Here is template init config for firebase:

```
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
  appId: "app-id",
  measurementId: "G-measurement-id"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); //how i should gives access to that?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a file that will execute exactly once and is not affected by react re-renders... I would suggest `App.js` for example(or create a separate file for firebase importing and exporting)

To access the firebase instance you created export it from the file after you initialized in

```js
export const firebaseInstance = firebase;
```